# Generate a random seeded hex color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I am using `'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);` to generate a random hex color on key press.

This is used to change the background color whenever a lowercase alpha key is pressed.

I want to alter this code to be seeded by the keycode.
How can I do this?

I tried `'#'+Math.floor(e.which*16777215).toString(16);` but this generates a 7 character code instead of 6?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: basically because the website is using jQuery perhaps someone could have suggested a jQuery version ;)

Comment: Oh, you mean like: `$.getRandomColour();`? I'm surprised no one suggested it - surely `there's a jQuery plugin for that`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By saying you want a "seeded" random number I'm assuming you want the same color every time the same key is pressed.  Unfortunately you can't control the [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) seed in JavaScript since it does not accept a seed as a parameter like in some other languages.

You could generate a random looking hex number with something like this:

```
Math.floor((Math.abs(Math.sin(seed) * 16777215))).toString(16);
```

This should generate an unique number for everything in the ASCII range, but some of the colors may very similar.

```js
function genColor (seed) {
  color = Math.floor((Math.abs(Math.sin(seed) * 16777215)));
  color = color.toString(16);
  // pad any colors shorter than 6 characters with leading 0s
  while(color.length < 6) {
    color = '0' + color;
  }

  return color;
}

let tableHTML = '';

for (let i=32; i < 127; i++) {
  color = genColor(i);
  tableHTML += `<tr style="background:#${color}"><td>${String.fromCharCode(i)}</td><td>#${color}</td></tr>`;
}

tableHTML = `<table>${tableHTML}</table>`;

$('#test').bind('keypress', function (evt) {
    $(this).css('background', '#' + genColor(evt.which));

});
$('body').append(tableHTML);
```

```css
#out, p, input { margin: 1em }
table {border-collapse: separate}
td {padding: 1em; border: 3px solid #fff; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out">Type in the input box to change its background color :<input id="test">
    <p>Below is a list of colors generated for ASCII 32 through 126</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey great solution! I know it's been a long time, but couldn't you avoid the % step since you are using sin that always belongs to [-1, 1]? Using abs also guarantees that the output always belongs to [0, 1] * 0xffffff.

Comment: @afe You are right, thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a `7` letter code because you are working with a number that cannot be represented as `6` characters in hexadecimal.

`16777215` (base 10) in base 16 is `FFFFFF`. If your decimal number grows *any* larger, another hexadecimal letter/digit will be used to express it.

To make your code work, just make sure `16777215` is the highest.

`222` seems to be the highest keycode possible (please correct me if I am mistaken):

```
Math.floor(e.which * 16777215 / 222).toString(16);
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy JavaScript to use would be this:

```
function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
        }
        return color;
    }
```

You can see it work here: http://sweb1.dmit.nait.ca/~bkoepke1/Random%20Colour%20Generator/

Comment: The OP already has code to generate random color values. They're asking for how to modify it to make the color value depend on the key pressed, which this doesn't help with.

Comment: `Math.floor( Math.random() * 16 )` would be preferred. Math.random() generates numbers in [0,1) – 1 excluded. Your version returns 0 and 15 with half the probability of the other numbers'.

Answer (score -2):

A hex colour code has 3 components from 00 to FF concatenated to form a single string. It isn't simply a 6 character hex number. So a random colour generator would be something like:

```
function randomHexColor() {
    var x, c = '#';
    var i = 3;
    while (i--) {
     x = (Math.random()*256|0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
     c += (x.length < 2? '0' : '') + x;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Add seeding as required.

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between a random 6-character hex number and 3 random 2-character hex numbers concatenated together, unless there's something wrong with the random number generator, and this doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Comment: @MuMind—yes, you're correct, where the components are 00 to FF giving 000000 to FFFFFF. Perhaps I was distracted by the decimal 0 to 255 range.