# FullCalendar: Event Colors based on Users

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to customize the fullcalendar events. There is only one event source and my event object look like this:

{ id = 1, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-02", end = "2013-10-06", allDay = true, userId= "abc" }

What i am trying to achieve is that based on User Id's i want to define the color for events.
The choice of color does not matter and can be random and the number of users is dynamic
for e.g.
All the events for UserId "abc" displays in black
All the events for UserId "xyz" displays in red, etc

Also, i am looking for suggestions if i can define by event source with multiple resources as: 
For "abc" - different event source
For "xyz" - different event source.

users are dynamic.

any suggestions:

this is how my calendar looks like

```
var calendar = {
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today, basicDay,basicWeek,month'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    buttonText: {
        today: 'Today',
        day: 'Day',
        week: 'Week',
        month: 'Month',
        prev: 'Prev', 
        next: 'Next', 

    },
    weekends: true, 
    editable: true,
    events: {
        ignoreTimezone: true,
        url: 'GetEvents',                              
        error: function () {
            alert('GetEvent Call Failed!');
        }
    }
};

myCalendar.fullCalendar(calendar);
```

Comment: It looks like nomatteus's answer has you covered, but I wanted to mention [a library](https://github.com/nluqo/autumn) I wrote that is designed exactly for this purpose. You can pass in a key like user id and get a color back. If you're able to set an attribute that has the user ID in it, it gets even easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the event color by passing the `eventBackgroundColor` parameter with each event ([Event object docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)).

---

For generating the colors, you'll want a "seeded random color". There's one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134122) (Javascript), and I've also used this Ruby method:

```
def random_hex(integer)
  srand integer
  (rand * 100000000).to_i.to_s(16)[0..5]
end
```

You would seed it with the User ID. The concept should be similar in other languages.